# Alcohol consumption project

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am doing a Pandas project on alcohol consumption. For your information, the dataset has the following columns:

| Continent | Country | Beer | Spirit | Wine |

The following is my code:

```
# Separating data by continent
# ----------------------------
data_asia   = data[data['Continent'] == 'Asia']
data_africa = data[data['Continent'] == 'Africa']
data_europe = data[data['Continent'] == 'Europe']
data_north  = data[data['Continent'] == 'North America']
data_south  = data[data['Continent'] == 'South America']
data_ocean  = data[data['Continent'] == 'Oceania']

top_5_asia_beer = data_asia.nlargest(5, ['Beer Servings'])[['Country', 'Beer Servings']]
top_5_asia_spir = data_asia.nlargest(5, ['Spirit Servings'])[['Country', 'Spirit Servings']]
top_5_asia_wine = data_asia.nlargest(5, ['Wine Servings'])[['Country', 'Wine Servings']]
top_5_asia_pure = data_asia.nlargest(5, ['Total Litres of Pure Alcohol'])[['Country', 'Total Litres of Pure Alcohol']]

top_5_africa_beer = data_africa.nlargest(5, ['Beer Servings'])[['Country', 'Beer Servings']]
top_5_africa_spir = data_africa.nlargest(5, ['Spirit Servings'])[['Country', 'Spirit Servings']]
top_5_africa_wine = data_africa.nlargest(5, ['Wine Servings'])[['Country', 'Wine Servings']]
top_5_africa_pure = data_africa.nlargest(5, ['Total Litres of Pure Alcohol'])[['Country', 'Total Litres of Pure Alcohol']]

top_5_europe_beer = data_europe.nlargest(5, ['Beer Servings'])[['Country', 'Beer Servings']]
top_5_europe_spir = data_europe.nlargest(5, ['Spirit Servings'])[['Country', 'Spirit Servings']]
top_5_europe_wine = data_europe.nlargest(5, ['Wine Servings'])[['Country', 'Wine Servings']]
top_5_europe_pure = data_europe.nlargest(5, ['Total Litres of Pure Alcohol'])[['Country', 'Total Litres of Pure Alcohol']]

top_5_north_beer = data_north.nlargest(5, ['Beer Servings'])[['Country', 'Beer Servings']]
top_5_north_spir = data_north.nlargest(5, ['Spirit Servings'])[['Country', 'Spirit Servings']]
top_5_north_wine = data_north.nlargest(5, ['Wine Servings'])[['Country', 'Wine Servings']]
top_5_north_pure = data_north.nlargest(5, ['Total Litres of Pure Alcohol'])[['Country', 'Total Litres of Pure Alcohol']]

top_5_south_beer = data_south.nlargest(5, ['Beer Servings'])[['Country', 'Beer Servings']]
top_5_south_spir = data_south.nlargest(5, ['Spirit Servings'])[['Country', 'Spirit Servings']]
top_5_south_wine = data_south.nlargest(5, ['Wine Servings'])[['Country', 'Wine Servings']]
top_5_south_pure = data_south.nlargest(5, ['Total Litres of Pure Alcohol'])[['Country', 'Total Litres of Pure Alcohol']]

top_5_ocean_beer = data_ocean.nlargest(5, ['Beer Servings'])[['Country', 'Beer Servings']]
top_5_ocean_spir = data_ocean.nlargest(5, ['Spirit Servings'])[['Country', 'Spirit Servings']]
top_5_ocean_wine = data_ocean.nlargest(5, ['Wine Servings'])[['Country', 'Wine Servings']]
top_5_ocean_pure = data_ocean.nlargest(5, ['Total Litres of Pure Alcohol'])[['Country', 'Total Litres of Pure Alcohol']]
```

I understand the ridiculousness of my code in terms of duplicity and repetitiveness. Can anyone please share tips and tricks to refactor the code?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to do with it. It seems a bit odd to store each top 5 in its own variable.

For starters, you can slice a DataFrame by continent using `.groupby`:

```
for continent, continent_data in data.groupby("Continent"):
    # `continent` is now the name of the continent (you don't have to type the continent names manually)
    # `continent_data` is a dataframe, being a subset of the `data` dataframe
```

**Edit based on first comment**: if you want to plot the variables, it's definitely not a good idea to store them each in a separate variable. Do you already know how you want to visualize your data? That's something you will need to work toward. I can't really see a top 5 countries for each type of alcoholic beverage for each continent in one plot.

```
continents = []
top5s = {}
for continent, continent_data in data.groupby("Continent"):
    continents.append(continent)
    for beverage_column in ["Beer Servings", "Spirit Servings", "Wine Servings"]:
        topcountries = continent_data.nlargest(5, beverage_column)
        # do something with the data, such as:
        print(f"Top 5 countries in {continent} for {beverage}:")
        for row in topcountries.iterrows():
            print(f"- {row.Country}: {row['beverage_column']} servings")
```

To be very exact: `groupby()` doesn't return an iterable of tuples, but actually just a GroupBy object that implements iterability (i.e. [the `__iter__()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.__iter__.html)).

Comment: Oh, I now realised that the groupby() function returns a tuple of categories and dataframe subsets. Thanks.

Sorry for not informing more, I actually intend to later make a graph for the top 5 of each drink category for each continent. Any advice for this?

Comment: See my edits :)

Comment: Yeah, I found out about GroupBy object in the documentation. Silly me for mistaking tuples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### sample_data

```
np.random.seed(42)

drinks = ["Beer", "Spirit", "Wine"]
continents = [
    "Asia",
    "Africa",
    "Europe",
    "North America",
    "South America",
    "Oceania",
]
countries = [f"country_{i}" for i in range(10)]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    (continents, countries), names=["continent", "country"]
)
data = np.random.randint(1_000_000, size=(len(index), len(drinks )))

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns, data=data).reset_index()
```

## data structures

The most jarring about this, is that each datapoint has it's own variable.

A first step would be to use dictionaries:

```
data_by_continent = {
    continent: df.loc[df["continent"] == continent]
    for continent in continents
}
```

Note that I used `.loc` to explicitly make a copy instead of a view to prevent changes in one part of the code contaminating another.

Then the spirit consumption per continent is:

```
spirit_per_continent = {
    continent: data.loc[
        data["Spirit"].nlargest(5).index, ["country", "Spirit"]
    ]
    for continent, data in data_by_continent.items()
}
```

and nested per beverage

```
consumption_per_drink_continent = {
    drink: {
        continent: data.loc[
            data[drink].nlargest(5).index, ["country", drink]
        ]
        for continent, data in data_by_continent.items()
    }
    for drink in drinks
}
```

## pandas groupby

If you reform your dataframe into a tidy format, you can use an easy groupby.

[`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) is a very handy method to shape a dataframe

```
df2 = pd.melt(
    df,
    id_vars=["continent", "country"],
    var_name="drink",
    value_name="consumption",
)
```

> ```
>   continent   country     drink   consumption
> ....
> 175   Oceania     country_5   Wine    456551
> 176   Oceania     country_6   Wine    894498
> 177   Oceania     country_7   Wine    899684
> 178   Oceania     country_8   Wine    158338
> 179   Oceania     country_9   Wine    623094
> ```

## groupby

now you can use `groupby`, and then later join on the index of `df2` to introduce the country

```
(
    df2.groupby(["continent", "drink"])["consumption"]
    .nlargest(5)
    .reset_index(["continent", "drink"])
    .sort_values(
        ["continent", "drink", "consumption"], ascending=[True, True, False]
    )
    .join(df2["country"])
)
```

> ```
>       continent   drink   consumption     country
> 17    Africa  Beer    953277  country_7
> 19    Africa  Beer    902648  country_9
> 15    Africa  Beer    527035  country_5
> 13    Africa  Beer    500186  country_3
> 14    Africa  Beer    384681  country_4
> ...   ...     ...     ...     ...
> 162   South America   Wine    837646  country_2
> 160   South America   Wine    742139  country_0
> 167   South America   Wine    688519  country_7
> 161   South America   Wine    516588  country_1
> 166   South America   Wine    136330  country_6
>
> 90 rows × 4 columns
> ```